# Factors and Conditions that Affect Election in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

While reading the documentation i came across the below lines:
Network Partitions
Network partitions affect the formation of a majority for an election. If a primary steps down and neither portion of the replica set has a majority the set will not elect a new primary. The replica set becomes read-only.

**To avoid this situation, place a majority of instances in one data center and a minority of instances in any other data centers combined.**

I am not understanding the bold line. Can someone explains what it means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, OP is referring to [Network Partitions section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#network-partitions) of the Replica Set Elections docs.

Suppose you have three datacenters, `A`, `B`, and `C`. Each datacenter has some nodes of your MongoDB replica set `rs`. `rs` has a total of 5 nodes. Due to a combination tornado / hurricane / shark attack causing a network partition, each datacenter becomes disconnected from the others. `A` can't talk to `B`, `B` can't talk to `C`, `A` can't talk to `B`, etc. If you have a majority (3) of members of `rs` in `A`, the replica set continues to be healthy, since the three members in `A` can elect one of their own as primary. The application will still be able to write to `rs` even while `B` and `C` are flooded / ensharked / torn apart by wind. If you split up the members of `rs` more evenly between replica sets, say with 2 in `A`, 2 in `B`, and 1 in `C`, the network partition would put `rs` in an unhealthy state where no primary could be elected. `rs` will be read-only and will not accept any writes until connectivity from `A` to at least one of `B` or `C` is restored or connectivity is restored between `B` and `C`.